# How to get a particular value from innerhtml in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Recently I am working with project a in which i want the value of `#page='+pid+'"`
from this embeded code of `innerhtml`. I have tried with index as position, but dit not get the desired result.
There is pageid value, which I want. I have also tried this:

```
var aPosition = aURL.indexOf(pid);
var res =aURL.charAt(aPosition)</code>
var aURL=document.getElementById('pdffile').innerHTML='<embed  src="../EyeLegalAdmin/wp-content/plugins/EyeLegalAdmin/Data/<?=$_GET['CaseId']?>/<?=$_GET['file']?>#page='+pid+'" type="application/pdf" height="618px" width="100%" onScroll="yes"  />';`
```

How can I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var x = " src=\"../EyeLegalAdmin/wp-content/plugins/EyeLegalAdmi/Data/<?=$_GET['CaseId']?>/<?=$_GET['file']?>#page='S'\"" ;

var arr = x.split("#");
var firstIndex = arr[1].indexOf("\'");
//var lastIndex =  arr[1].lastIndexOf("\'");
var ressult = arr[1].substr(firstIndex+1 , 1 );
```